# Eager Loading with filters (where clauses)?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

Is it possible to add where clause to an eager loading method on a model? For example:

```
class User extends Model {
  public function sources()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Source::class,          // The related model
            UserNetwork::class,  // The intermediate table that connects this model with the related model.
            'user_id',               // The intermediate table's column that connects to this model.
            'network_id',          // The related table's column that connects to the secondLocalKey.
            'id',               // This model's column that connects to the firstKey.
            'network_id'          // The intermediate table's column that connects the related model.
        )
            ->where('xyz_id', $this->xyz_id);
    }
}
```

Doing this `User::with('sources')->get()` returns a collection of users with the sources relation but the sources collection is empty. When I run `User::first()->sources()->get()` it returns just the collection of sources with the actual data.

Isn't eager loading supposed to 'eager load' all the records instead of having to specify the the first() record?

Comment: `User::with('sources')->first()->sources` should return the same thing as `User::first()->sources()->get()`; a `Collection` of `Source` records that belong to that `User`. `get()` and `first()` are mostly irrelevant in your case. The biggest difference is `->sources` vs `->sources()->get()`; the first is an eager-loaded Collection, the 2nd is a whole new query, that eventually returns the same Collection.

Comment: In my case it gets all the sources, not the ones i want. I have to also filter by the 'xyz_id' column. If I add the where clause (filter) eager loading stops working.

Comment: Ah my apologies, I missed that this was a `hasManyThrough()`. You might need to post your migrations for each of the tables being connected, and maybe the other models too. At a glance, it looks off when compared to the example given in the documentation, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: I found https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships but it doesn't provide a hasManyThrough relationship. Working on trying to see if I can still use it somehow.

Comment: what do you mean from ```where('xyz_id', $this->xyz_id)``` you mean ```sources.xyz_id == user_networks.xyz_id```?

Comment: @BabakAsadzadeh, no source.xyz_id = user.xyz_id

Comment: i think you have to do a raw join it is not possible with eloquent models